# Data analysis code running differently on coworker's computer

Tags: python, pycharm, spyder, data-analysis

I want to ensure that any scripts me and my coworkers write can be run by each other. I've run into some inexplicable problems recently, which I don't know are machine/platform/software/versioning issues. Unfortunately, we often don't have the time to test why something isn't working.

The most obvious difference my coworker and I is that his setup is on Spyder and mine is PyCharm. We are both using Windows 10 Education and the latest python and pandas.

Some of the problems I've encountered:

- his script will delete the last unit in a number which read in as float for him (10.0 -> 10), but deletes the last unit of a number which read in as integer for me (10 -> 1)
- his script will read in a multiindex xlsm file and perform operations on it, mine will say the relevant index doesn't exist

I would appreciate any knowledge or tips from people who have encountered this behavior/challenge.

Comment: Can you provide the code that's causing the differences between machines?

Comment: Unfortunately, my org has privacy concerns, and to dummy out all the variables to the point of the error would be a lot. I'm hoping for general advice from others who have encountered this.

Comment: My advice is to use the exact same setup in both machines, i.e. Python, Numpy, Pandas and all other libraries you use in your project. Even bugfix version differences (e.g. Numpy `1.17.1` and `1.17.2`) could introduce these inconsistencies. After that, you should run your file in a system terminal (i.e. by calling `python my_file.py` directly) to avoid possible differences created by each environment (i.e. Spyder vs. PyCharm).

Answer (score 0):

I would say your best bet is to set up an app server(Flask) and serve the code from a machine that gets the output expected (Be it something local or an EC2 instance or whatever). Then there is one code base and one platform, instead of going down the rabbit hole. Also a lot easier to maintain.